# closed form of a simple binomial weighted series

Tags: combinatorics

Does it exists a closed form (also approximating) for the following binomial weighted series?

$$
\sum_{k=1}^n {n \choose k} \cdot k
$$

Comment: I just write an extra answer if you want a method without derivatives.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Without calculus answer:**

Is easy to prove the next **Lemma**,

> **Lemma:** $\boxed{k\dbinom{n}{k}=n\dbinom{n-1}{k-1}}.$

Therefore by **Lemma**,

$$\sum_{k=1}^{n}k\dbinom{n}{k}=n\sum_{k=1}^{n}\dbinom{n-1}{k-1}.$$

Then by binomial Newton's expression,

$$\sum_{k=1}^{n}k\dbinom{n}{k}=n\sum_{k=0}^{n-1}\dbinom{n-1}{k}1^k1^{n-1-k}=n2^{n-1}\square$$

Answer (score 3):

By the binomial theorem:
$$
(x + 1)^n = \sum_{k=0}^{n} {n \choose k} x^k
$$

Differentiate both sides with respect to $x$:

$$
n (x + 1)^{n-1} = \sum_{k=1}^{n} {n \choose k} k x^{k-1}
$$

Plug in $x = 1$:

$$
n 2^{n-1} = \sum_{k=1}^{n} {n \choose k} k
$$

Comment: Many thanks Ayman.